# json file creation from multiple dictionaries in python

Tags: python, json, file

I have 3 different types of properties like below

```
devices
iphone
ipad
ipod
watch

city
NY
SFO
LA
NJ

Company
Apple
Samsung
Walmart
```

Now I want create a `json` file using the properties.

For example for `devices` I have done like below.

I created a `dictionary` manually in `python` like below.

```
device_dict = {'device1': 'iphone', 'device2': 'ipad', 'device3': 'ipod', 'device4': 'watch'}
```

Then converted the `dictionary` to a `json` file like below.

```
import json
out_file = open("test.json","w")
json.dump(my_dict,out_file, indent=4)                                    
out_file.close()
```

I am able to create `3` separate `json` like below but How can I do for all the `3` properties into a single file.

Comment: The easiest solution is to create either a list of the three dicts, or a dict of the three dicts, and `json.dump` that.

Comment: For example: `big_dict = {'device': device_dict, 'city': city_dict, 'company': company_dict}` then `json.dump(big_dict, out_file, indent=4)`.

Comment: (Although I'm not sure why your `device_dict` is a dict rather than a list in the first place…)

Comment: @abarnert I am still learning `Python` when i looked online I found articles to create json from dict mostly. I thought that is the easy way arround. Could you please let me know how I can create `json` file using lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON allows list structures, so, without knowing what its for, the best way to save it in my opinion is as such:

```
data = {
    'devices': ['iphone', 'ipad', 'ipod', 'watch'],
    'cities': ['NY', 'SFO', 'LA', 'NJ'],
    'companies': ['Apple', 'Samsung', 'Walmart']
}
```

There is no point in naming something `device1` when its obvious that it is the first item in the **list** of `devices`. When you want the value of the first device:

```
device1 = data['devices'][0]
```

This stores all the information in a format you can parse easily.